# How to open default music app into my application

Tags: iphone, openurl

In my app I need to open message app and music app in tapping on button.

For open message I used code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms:"]];
```

Please, suggest me what should I write to open music app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The URL scheme for Music app is `music://`.