# How to open default music app into my application ios 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, openurl

Based in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207883/how-to-open-default-music-app-into-my-application).

Works perfect but me in old ios versions, but in ios 10 not works.

**This is my code:**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"music://"]];
```

I'm testing with

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"music://"] options:@{} completionHandler:nil];
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `Privacy - Media Library Usage Description` in .plist. That solves the problem

Comment: For more info on all iOS10 necessary permissions. check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38498347/3670829